# Updating Table through matching - Access, VBA, SQL

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a complicated scenario and had been scratching my head over this, hopefully someone can help me with this logic:

I have two table, table A has Field 1,2,3,4,5. Table B has field v,w,x,y,z.

The logic that I want to do is the following:
go through the rows in table A, for each row, if Field 3 matches Field w (which would have multiple row in Table B as well), see if Field 4 matches (x or y or z), if there's a match, update table A's Field 5 with Field v.

I tired putting X,y,z into an array, but got stuck from there on how to proceed. I've seen multiple example online to update the recordset, but not the field in a table with all these conditions.

Is this possible? If it is can someone give me a hint? Thanks!

Comment: What you say field is called column in excel. Your question is not clear when you say "if there's a match, update table A's Field 5 with Field v." Do you plan to update the whole Column 5 or just the corresponding cells?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the general gist of the core logic : far from complete, but that's the structure

```
  For Each rowA In tblA
    For Each rowB In tblB
      If rowA!Field3 = rowB!FieldW Then
        If rowA!Field4 = rowB!FieldX Or rowA!Field4 = rowB!FieldY Or rowA!Field4 = rowB!FieldZ Then
          rowA!Field5 = rowB!FieldV
          rowA.Update
        End If
      End If
    Next
  Next
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

This is very close to the logic that I want to implement. My issue right now is how do code the solution. So for example on the first line, I'd need to move through the various rows and specify a single row to run the For statement... which is the hard part imo

Comment: Any idea how this can be fixed?

'CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO SundayPositions (EmployeeName) VALUES ('Filled') WHERE SundayPositions.SundayPositionID.Value = SundayPost!SundayPositionID"

SundayPositions is the table name, Sunday PositionID is the Field name, SundayPost is the record set.

Comment: just remove the `.Value` - INSERT INTO SundayPositions (EmployeeName) VALUES ('Filled') WHERE SundayPositions.SundayPositionID= SundayPost!SundayPositionID

Comment: You dont put `.Value` in SQL, you use it in VBA/.NET code for objects in your class